# Import Azure Storage Library to Eclipse, Java

Tags: eclipse, azure-storage

I'm a novice to coding and cloud storage and need some step by step guidance on how to set up my Eclipse so I could start working with Microsoft Azure Cloud storage.

So basically I'm following this tutorial for Azure file storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage

But when I tried to import the library to in my Eclipse, I got the error "the import cannot be resolved"

```
// Include the following imports to use blob APIs.
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*; 
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.*;
```

I guess I am missing some libraries. I previously learnt to adds some external libraries though Jar files, I searched for Jar for Azure cloud, but couldn't find any. This page seems relevant but I don't know how to use it. https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java

Can someone please shed some light?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. 
For other novice programmer going through the same struggle, here is how I did it

1.Install Azure Toolkit for Eclipse, follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/eclipse/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation

2.Restart Eclipse

3.Rightclick the project you want to use the Azure library, then Properties>>Java Build Path>>Libraries tab>> Add Library>> Select Package for Microsoft Azure Libraries for Java>>Finish